# Reactor: delayElement doesn't work with Flux

Tags: kotlin, spring-webflux, project-reactor, reactor

So I want to use Flux to run each Mono task and wait each task for 2 seconds. Here's what I have tried

```
val test = { x: Int ->
      Mono.just(x)
        .log()
        .doOnNext { println("Number: $it") }
    }


Flux.fromIterable(listOf(1, 2, 3))
    .flatMap { number ->
      test(number)
         .delayElement(Duration.ofSeconds(2))
    }
    .collectList()
    //.subscribeOn(Schedulers.single()) <- just try to run on the same thread didn't work either
   .block()
```

Here's the result

```
01:58:21.398 [Test worker] DEBUG reactor.util.Loggers$LoggerFactory - Using Slf4j logging framework
01:58:21.470 [Test worker] INFO reactor.Mono.Just.1 - | onSubscribe([Synchronous Fuseable] Operators.ScalarSubscription)
01:58:21.472 [Test worker] INFO reactor.Mono.Just.1 - | request(unbounded)
01:58:21.473 [Test worker] INFO reactor.Mono.Just.1 - | onNext(1)
Number: 1
01:58:21.477 [Test worker] INFO reactor.Mono.Just.1 - | onComplete()
01:58:21.477 [Test worker] INFO reactor.Mono.Just.2 - | onSubscribe([Synchronous Fuseable] Operators.ScalarSubscription)
01:58:21.477 [Test worker] INFO reactor.Mono.Just.2 - | request(unbounded)
01:58:21.478 [Test worker] INFO reactor.Mono.Just.2 - | onNext(2)
Number: 2
01:58:21.478 [Test worker] INFO reactor.Mono.Just.2 - | onComplete()
01:58:21.478 [Test worker] INFO reactor.Mono.Just.3 - | onSubscribe([Synchronous Fuseable] Operators.ScalarSubscription)
01:58:21.479 [Test worker] INFO reactor.Mono.Just.3 - | request(unbounded)
01:58:21.479 [Test worker] INFO reactor.Mono.Just.3 - | onNext(3)
Number: 3
01:58:21.479 [Test worker] INFO reactor.Mono.Just.3 - | onComplete()
```

As you can see on the timestamp delayElement doesn't seem to work even though it runs on the same thread (Test worker). What I did wrong here?

Edited: I don't really understand how it works but instead of adding delayElement inside of flatmap I add delayElements on top of it and it works fine.

```
Flux.fromIterable(listOf(1, 2, 3))
    .delayElements(Duration.ofSeconds(2))
    .flatMap { number ->
      test(number)
    }
    .collectList()
    //.subscribeOn(Schedulers.single()) <- just try to run on the same thread didn't work either
   .block()
```

the result

```
03:21:29.825 [Test worker] DEBUG reactor.util.Loggers$LoggerFactory - Using Slf4j logging framework
03:21:29.926 [Test worker] INFO reactor.Flux.Array.1 - | onSubscribe([Synchronous Fuseable] FluxArray.ArraySubscription)
03:21:29.929 [Test worker] INFO reactor.Flux.Array.1 - | request(32)
03:21:29.930 [Test worker] INFO reactor.Flux.Array.1 - | onNext(1)
03:21:29.935 [Test worker] INFO reactor.Flux.Array.1 - | onNext(2)
03:21:29.936 [Test worker] INFO reactor.Flux.Array.1 - | onNext(3)
03:21:29.936 [Test worker] INFO reactor.Flux.Array.1 - | onComplete()
Thread[parallel-1,5,main] What is this 1 31
Thread[parallel-2,5,main] What is this 2 33
Thread[parallel-3,5,main] What is this 3 35
```

Comment: To me, it's not clear what functionality you are trying to achieve here. Are you looking to sequentially process each `Mono` and wait 2 seconds before processing the next `Mono`?

Comment: why your log statement doesn't show the delay is because your log shows only the conversation between the `doOnNext` statement and the `Mono.just(x)` the `doOnNext` does an unbounded request `request(unbounded)` for items from the `Mono` and the `Mono`answers with `onNext(2)` and returning an item.

Comment: @MichaelMcFadyen yes, exactly !

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that in the first one you are doing the delay in flatmap, Knowing that flatmap  is with prefatch and concurrency 256 and 32 this means that the code in flatmap will run in paralel and all items will be delayed 2 seconds but will be executed (subscribed) in the same time
if you want to have it inside you need to use concatMap with prefatch 1

```
Flux.fromIterable(listOf(1, 2, 3))
.concatmap ( number ->
  test(number)
     .delayElement(Duration.ofSeconds(2))
,1)
.collectList()
.block()
```

This will make the code inside wait till the preview finish requesting items 1 by 1

But more clean solution is to delay it after